# Setting text based on objects using eureka

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

i'm trying to set the value based to name in a realm object however it keep showing `Ladder {` as text in cell instead of the `name`. here is my code

```
    <<< MultipleSelectorRow<Ladder>("Rank") {
           $0.hidden = Condition.predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$Game == nil"))
           $0.title = $0.tag


           }.cellUpdate { cell, row in

               let formvalues = self.form.values()
               let game = formvalues["Game"] as! Game
               let ranks = Array(game.ranks)
               row.options = ranks
               row.displayValueFor = { (rowValue: Set<Ladder>?) in
                   return rowValue?.map({ $0.name }).sorted().joined(separator: ", ")
               }


               cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16)

               cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
               cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
               cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

       }
```

ranks output

```
[Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53472;
    name = Bronze;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53473;
    name = Silver;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53474;
    name = Gold;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53475;
    name = Platinium;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53476;
    name = Diamond;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53477;
    name = Master;
}, Ladder {
    id = 58268b08f5f51a16b8d53478;
    name = Challenger;
}]
```

realm model

```
class Ladder: Object {

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

Comment: two different questions. the one is the output of the value this is the options shoing in the text cell